# Number of 2x2 Jordan blocks of a 2x2 matrix

Tags: matrices, finite-groups, finite-fields

On the [groupprops wiki](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_special_linear_group_of_degree_two_over_a_finite_field#Summary_for_odd_field_size) for $SL_2(\mathbb F_q)$ it says there are 4 conjugacy classes in the case of a Jordan block of size 2.

Aren't the possible forms just
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$? What else  is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the only possible Jordan forms. But it is possible for two matrices to have the same Jordan form, but not be conjugate under $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$ (though according to the table you link to, they will still be conjugate under $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$).

For example,
$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ have the same Jordan form, but are not equivalent under $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$.

The two representatives you are missing are $\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} -1&-1\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$

**Note that this all assumes that $q$ is odd.**